# git squash on another branch (except master)

Tags: git, git-squash

I am new to `git squash`, I created a new branch `a` from the `master`
and then did a lot of changes and push to branch `a`. Now 8 commits on
branch `a` and I to have squash all 3 commits to single one but when I
was doing it did not work for me. Please see below steps that I have followed:

```
step-1: git rebase -i HEAD~3
response: 
 pick c69a5da4 Items API setup
 pick 83686433 rake task for Item ES index
 pick ee479ace Items API report setup with test case integrations
```

I made some changes to the response and the updated response is:

```
pick c69a5da4 Items API setup
pick 83686433 rake task for Item ES index
squash ee479ace Items API report setup with test case integrations
```

after that, I saved this file and changed the commit message but now still showing two commits when I checked log.

```
o [branch-name] Items API report setup with test case integrations            
o Items API setup
```

but when I have checked to branch `a` from github repo then there was no changes in branch `a`, So where I am doing wrong could anyone please guide me.

Comment: Did you push your changes to github repo?

Comment: @DariaPydorenko Yes i pushed to branch `a`